# Verify CheckBox Checked in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I needed verify if exists a checkbox unchecked in my form.
I have an verification in my btnSend_OnClick event. If exists one checkbox unchecked, it enable my Label with message error. But if I have other rows, and it's checked, how it's is an foreach, don't show my mesage error!
How I build an verification, in C#, that verifies if exists a checkbox unchecked and shows message immediately to user and stops my foreach? I'm clear?

my cs:

```
protected void btnSend_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox2");

        if (check.Checked == false && check2.Checked == false)
        {
            lblErrorCheck.Visible = true;
        }

        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div class="control-group error">
        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorCheck" runat="server" class="control-label" for="inputError"
            Visible="false">Please, check a checkbox for each folder!</asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
        CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessGroup" HeaderText="Access Group" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Access to Read" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_ChangeCheck"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Access to Modify" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_ChangeCheck"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" class="btn btn-large" runat="server" Text="Send Request Access"
        OnClick="btnSend_OnClick" align="left" />
</div>
<div align="center" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/home_back_48.png"
        NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx">homepage</asp:HyperLink>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected void btnSend_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
{
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox2");

    if (!check.Checked  && !check2.Checked)
    {
        lblErrorCheck.Visible = true;
        break;
    }

}
}
```

Hope it helps you.

The `break;` clause here tells the loop to stop when it reaches that line.
Take a took at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  for more details.

Comment: Tks for your help! It's worked to one checkbox. I'm testing with 6 lines, and when I sets the last checkBox unchecked, the send occurs without error. It's wrong, in this case, have that show my error.

Comment: Is it throws Exception or give some other error.That code is work on `click` of button then hows possible to throw error on `uncheck` checkbox.Please elaborate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand you. But if you want the loop to stop when a checkbox is not unchecked use this:

```
if (check.Checked == false && check2.Checked == false)
    {
        lblErrorCheck.Visible = true;
        break;
    }
```